# Redownload zip file again without rewriting zip files - ZipArchive PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, php-ziparchive

So I create some php code to create a zip file using ZipArchive. This will create a zip file and download it. To initiate the download, I'm putting the link to php file containing the php code below in an iframe. This iframe is then inserted into an html document.

So whenever the html document loads, the downloader will initiate. I created the onload attribute in the iframe tag which will call a function to display a redownload button.

So if the user clicks the redownload button, I want it to download that same zip file again, but not recreate zip file process again. How do I do that?

Thanks!

**MY HTML CODE:**

```
<iframe src="phpfile.php" onload="myFrameLoad(this)"></iframe>
```

**MY PHP CODE for phpfile.php:**

```php
$coreFiles = Array('blah.jpg', 'blo.png');
# create new zip object
$coreZip = new ZipArchive();

# create a temp file & open it
$tmp_file = tempnam('.','');
$coreZip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);

# loop through each file
foreach($coreFiles as $coreFile){
    # download file
    $download_file = file_get_contents($coreFile);
    #add it to the zip
    $coreZip->addFromString(basename($coreFile),$download_file);
}

# close zip
$coreZip->close();

# send the file to the browser as a download   
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=myZipFolder.zip');
header('Content-type: application/zip');
readfile($tmp_file);
```

Comment: you would have to store the file somewhere unpacked. and look for it first before calling ZipArchive.  Yes this takes up a lot of space after a while

Comment: _"So whenever the html document loads, the downloader will initiate"_ , _"So if the user clicks the redownload button"_ Where is "redownload button" located?

Comment: @guest271314 The redownload button will appear above the iframe in the html document

Comment: @Forbs That might be a not bad idea. If I go this route, I want the file to be deleted after awhile. Is it possible to store the zip file in a sessionstorage or localstorage?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XMLHttpRequest()` or `fetch()` to get file as `Blob`, create `Blob URL` using `URL.createObjectURL()`, store reference to `Blob URL`. At subsequent `click` at element check if `Blob URL` is defined, if `true`, call `window.open()` with `Blob URL` as first parameter, `"_self"` as second parameter. The approach should store a single copy of the file at client browser as a `Blob URL` until user closes `document` which created the reference.

html

```
<button>download</button>
```

javascript

```
let url = w = void 0;
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (url) {
    w = window.open(url, "_self")
  } 
  else {
    fetch("phpfile.php")
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => {
      url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      w = window.open(url, "_self")
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }
});
```

where [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch#Browser_compatibility) is not supported

```
let url = w = void 0;
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (url) {
    w = window.open(url, "_self")
  } 
  else {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "phpfile.php", true);
    request.responseType = "blob";
    request.onload = () => {
      url = URL.createObjectURL(request.response);
      w = window.open(url, "_self")
    }
    request.onerror = err => console.error(err);
    request.send(null);
  }
});
```

Comment: @HoaHo Which version of safari are you trying at?

Comment: safari v10.0 on macOS Sierra

Comment: [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob#Browser_compatibility) is supported starting at version 5.1, however [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch#Browser_compatibility) is not supported. See updated post

Comment: So I've tested your code. It still doesn't work in Safari, but it works in other browsers. Another thing is that it's still recreating the zip file again. I want it to redownload that same zip file again without recreating a new zip file.

Comment: _"Another thing is that it's still recreating the zip file again."_ Not sure how `javascript` at Question would create a new `.zip` file? Only one request should be made to server.